# One computer in Windows 7 workgroup cannot see network share

Tags: network-shares

One computer on my home network suddenly cannot see the network share to map it.  It used to work fine.  All other computers in the workgroup see the share, and the problem computer can see all other computers in the workgroup.  I am administrator.

1. I can ping the share at its IP address.
2. I can access the share’s configuration utility using its IP address.
3. When trying to map the drive, the Browse command does not see the share.
4. I cannot map it using its name `\\TS-HTGL4A5\share` or its IP address.
5. Network discovery and file sharing are turned on, password protection is off.
6. I turned Windows firewall off, no change.

Comment: How many computers in the network?

Comment: confirm that the pc is in the same workgroup, and that for the account accessing the server, the username/password are the same on both ends. do you configure a wins server address?  also, not sure if this was a typeo, but the UNC syntax is `\\servername\share` (note two hacks at the front).

Comment: Did you try a System Restore back to a point in time when it WAS working?

Comment: I tried a restore, no dice. Workgroups are the same. No WINS server address.

Answer (score 1):

I have simillar problem when my windows 7 network card was configurate to have two ip's
192.168.1.x and 192.168.0.x.
My workgroup computers works on x.x.1.x.
After i deleted seccound ip x.x.0.x win 7 found workgroup pc's and connect to them by name. (connecting by ip was able all the time)

Its strange becouse in the same workgroup i have win xp with two ip's: 192.168.1.x and 192.168.0.x.
and its work with no problem.